# How to deal with modifying global state of system under test?

Tags: playwright

I am trying to run a test that verifies the functionality of some system global state variables. For example: "enable feature A, test that feature A works, disable feature A, test that feature A no longer works". I cannot create a separate system for each test, so the state will be shared between tests.

The bulk of my tests do not touch this global state or depend on it and I want to parallelize as much as possible, is there a way (such as a mutex) to run most of the tests in parallel but a single test (or group of tests) as mutually exclusive with other tests related to the state?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run them all in one file, and either set the file to run in [serial mode](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#serial-mode) (though that mode isn’t recommended) or to [use separate projects to match the separate files](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#different-tests-different-configuration) and set the fullyParallel option to false for that file’s project.